# Chaning shape of the Image based on density

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image below

[image]

Now what I want to do is that I want to move a mxn window that is calculated in proportion(not exactly) to the size of the Image.Then I would move the window horizontally in the image and if I found some dense region(threshold is constant like 0.35) I would make center pixel to be 1 other wise 0.

I have the following code in matlab

```
function result=imagePixelDensity(Image,thresh)
    [WidthI,HeightI]=size(Image);
    WidthW=round(0.04*WidthI);   % window width
    HeightW=round(0.02*HeightI);  %window height

    if(mod(WidthW,2)~=1)         % to make odd dimension
        WidthW=WidthW+1;        
    end
    if(mod(HeightW,2)~=1)       % to make odd dimension
        HeightW=HeightW+1;
    end

    minNumber=min(WidthW,HeightW);  % since height and width could vary so I am selecting lowest
    WidthW=minNumber;
    HeightW=minNumber;

    totalDensity=WidthW*HeightW;     % total counts of 1 in a window
    colLimit=WidthI-WidthW+1;        % since window cannot cover the whole width of Image(as it has its own dimension)  so I need to restrict its col movements
    rowLimit=HeightI-HeightW+1;      % since window cannot cover the whole height of Image(as it has its own dimension)  so I need to restrict its row movements
    stepRow=0;
    stepCol=0;
    for r=1:rowLimit
        for c=1:colLimit
            if(((HeightW+stepRow)<=rowLimit) && (WidthW+stepCol)<=colLimit)

                Temp=Image(r:HeightW+stepRow,c:WidthW+stepCol);   % get a chunk equal to window size from image
                dens=sum(Temp(:))/totalDensity;                   % calculating density
                rowMid=(r+HeightW+stepRow)/2;                     % row index of center of chunk 
                colMid=(c+WidthW+stepCol)/2;                      % col index of center of chunk    


                if(dens>=thresh)
                    Image(rowMid,colMid)=1;   % making that center pixel to 1 in the original image
                else
                    Image(rowMid,colMid)=0;
                end     
            end
             stepCol=stepCol+1;
        end
       stepRow=stepRow+1;
    end
    result =Image;
end
```

The result should be that the region which I have marked as red since these are denser region will become rectangular region as pixels would be 1s there.

But I am NOT getting the required results(Actually Nothing in happening at all).

Can somebody guide me here or has better Idea?

Comment: "But I am NOT getting the required results."  What are you getting.

Comment: Nothing at all actually......it is not transforming the image at all let alone getting results

Comment: I dont really undestand. Your code detects in what part of the images are " a hihg density of white" and when there is a high density, you make 1 pixel of the area white. Well, most likely, it was already white, wasnt it?

Comment: I don't understand the constraint on the shape of the area - your red boxes differ in shape and size. Could you explain more fully please?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `Image(rowMid,colMid)=1;`

`rowMid` and `colMid` are scalars, meaning single values, so you are not making "all white", but just a single pixel. You need something like

```
Image(rowMid-winsize/2:rowMid+winsize/2,colMid-winsize/2:colMid+winsize/2)=1;
```

Additionally, I'd use `Imageaux` or `result`. because if you modify the original image, then you'll detect that chuck in the next iteration. Do not modify the input data.